# I want loaded index.html from the file system rather than severed from a host

Tags: ember.js, deployment, httpserver

When I run the project at http://localhost:4200, it working fine .but I want open index.html directly use browser (like file:///super-rentals/dist/index.html), it seems like didn't working. Anyone know why? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are missing a valid drive descriptor.

You need a path (on a Windows system) with a drive letter like

```
file:///C:\super-rentals/dist/index.html
```

or a UNC path like

```
file:///\\NetworkSharename/super-rentals/dist/index.html
```

to get this to work.

Comment: Thank you, I got the answer.
1.We need change the environment.js, rootURL: 'file:///super-rentals/dist/'.
2.Change the locationType to 'hash'.
Now, it should be working when you open the file:///...index.html in browser.
But, if still not working ,  please check whether there are some resource(like images or fonts) are not in your assets folder.